# Gmail signature removes text-decoration: none from links

Tags: html, css, gmail

Is there any way to set link `text-decoration: none` because of underline? I was looking for on stackoverflow, but nothings works. There is no underline first, but when I send email, underline is visible.

```
<a href="www.google.com">Link</a>

<a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none;">Link</a>

<a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none !important;">Link</a>

<a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none !important; text-decoration: none">Link</a>

<a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration-color: transparent">Link</a>

<a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <span style="text-decoration: none">Link</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding !important :

HTML

```
<a src = "www.google.com" id = "link"/>
```

CSS

```
#link {
    text-decoration : none !important ;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Gmail removes also all CSS id and classes. But a { text-decoration: none !important; } also not works.